# Sort on enum field using different sort orders

Tags: c#, list, sorting, enums

I have a Class called Item: wich contains various fields as

```
public class Item{
 private string name;
 private enume prop;
}
```

They got get and set-Methods.

while enume is a enum:

```
public enum enume{
 offensive
 defensive
 support
}
```

Now i got a `List<Item>`. I want to sort the list based on a specific order of the enum, for example

1. support,
2. defensive,
3. offensive.

But i also want to sort other orders like

1. offensive,
2. support,
3. defensive.

I did read many topics on stackoverflow, but i think none of them got 2 or more sorting orders. I order the Items by name using the Sort-Method:

`inventar.Sort((x,y) => string.Compare(x.getName(),y.getName()));`

But i dont get how i sort by enum with different orders.

Sorry for the bad code formatting, i just dont get it.

I Hope you can help me :)

/edited, hope it helps.

Comment: Is there anything you tried, and any code you can share?

Comment: `inventar.Sort((x,y) => string.Compare(x.getName(),y.getName()));` i use that to sort the Items by name, but i cant figure out how to sort by a enum more than once. I've tried to give a priority to the enum-entrys, but that only works if i want to sort it in one specific order if i am not wrong?

Comment: First of all... those are not properties, but fields, unless you're not showing us all of the code.  Something also tells me that you've accidentally left them as private.  Please show us more code.

Comment: You should really read about "How to use the IComparable and IComparer interfaces"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you create a dictionary for the sort order, you can use that for fast conversion from the enum to a sorting order:

```
Dictionary<enume, int> sort = new Dictionary<enume, int>();
sort.Add(enume.support, 0);
sort.Add(enume.defensive, 1);
sort.Add(enume.offensive, 2);
```

Now just sort on the conversion:

```
List<Item> result = items.OrderBy(i => sort[i.enume]).ToList();
```

To sort the enum values in a different way, just put the values in the dictionary with different numbers:

```
sort.Add(enume.offensive, 0);
sort.Add(enume.support, 1);
sort.Add(enume.defensive, 2);
```

Comment: @user2864740: I think that the OP was referring to different arrangements of the order of enum values, but sorting the items within each enum value will most likely also be useful.

Comment: Works perfectly, thanks to you :). Sorry btw for my bad question and code, first time i posting here^^